# Issue with SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm having an issue with our SQL Reporting Services and I'm hoping, someone, anyone can help me.

In our beta environment it appears that newer patients will not have their reports generated. However, if I go further back to some of the older patients, they do get generated. In the development environment it creates the reports without a problem.

All stored procedures and data generated are exactly the same. I looked through the logs and nothing seemed to be out of the ordinary. I'm at a complete and total loss on how to debug this.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to debug or see any kind of error or warning generated?

I know this bug is vague, but I'm not sure what else I can provide without going into gritty detail.

**EDIT: Added more details and clarification in response to Jamie F**

I should note that a report is "generated", but the fields are not filled out. Now, to get more specific...

- A patient, or rather a patient ID is the main parameter for the report. There are also 3 medical categories that don't change, two date parameters, and a disease state.
- Newer patients (patients added to the database most recently) do not fill out the report. Somewhat older patients, fill out a portion. And much older patients fill everything out when available.
- (If I'm understanding correctly) A report is run upon request, in other words, they're not set to be auto-generated on some sort of schedule.

I have installed [MS SQL Reporting Services Log Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/bi/en-us/Community/BILabs/Pages/ReportingServicesLogViewer.aspx) but nothing seemed out of the ordinary there.

Like I mentioned above, reports get generated in the development environment, but not for the beta. I'm still at a loss and haven't made much progress since posting this question.

The data source is from an SQL server being called with a stored procedure. The data returned for the patients, old or new is pretty much the same. Some dates and values are different, but that in general they look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel like a complete idiot. The problem turned out to be an incorrect data source. Instead of the Report Services pointing to the *HealthAlpha* database, it was pointing to *Health*_ *Alpha*

So when I looked over it it seemed ok. Frustrations are abound. X(

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give many details, so I'm making these assumptions:

- A "patient" is a parameter for the report.
- The patients for which reports fail, cause a failure 100% of the time: that it isn't an intermittent problem.
- The report runs for one patient at a time.

The problem is either in retrieving the data for the report, or in the display of that data.

So first determine which of those two is causing the problem. Open the data source in BIDS and make sure it executes, particularly when providing a problem patient as a parameter.

If you get data back, compare that data very closely with the data provided for a working report. If you don't get data, look into the data source for the report. ( You don't indicate what the data source is: SQL? Stored Procedure?)

Start there and track the problem down one either into the report or into the data source.

Comment: I updated the question that gives some more information. I've been focusing mostly on the data and everything seems legit, however, I've yet to figure out or debug how the report is being generated. Please feel free to provide more suggestions. Thanks for the feedback regardless.